# Disable last item in list view using dragndrop library

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I am using DragNDrop library for re ordering list view. But what I exactly need is that, the last element of the list view should be static. It should not move when some one try to re order. How can I implement it? Should I use some other libraries for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add it as a footer:

```
View footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
yourListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `RecyclerView` which offers more control and flexibility for the user interaction. There is some interesting library out there already implementing the user action like **Swipe-to-delete**, **Swipe-to-reorder**... And you could add you own behaviours to it depending of the position like you wanted to do. [AdvancedRecyclerView](https://github.com/StephenVinouze/AdvancedRecyclerView)

For example, you could just do nothing `onSwiped()` if the position is the last one as you wanted to accomplish.